# How to replace or resolve __TVOS_PROHIBITED dependencies in unistd.h

Tags: ios, posix, xcode7, tvos, unistd.h

I'm trying to compile a dependent libraries from the source code and I've got this error:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS9.0.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:446:8:
>   note: 'fork' has been explicitly marked unavailable here pid_t
>   fork(void) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

The thing is that I don't actually even need this functionality. When I compile this code for iOS and run it under tvOS then it works.
But I can not submit the application because it contains code compiled for iOS.

What would be the good trick to substitute there a dummy fork() function so it compiles OK (believing that it is not actually used by my specific use-cases).

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way round this.  You cannot create processes under iOS and tvOS is 90% iOS, so the same restriction applies.

You'll have to conditionally compile-out that section of code for iOS/tvOS.